# Symfony 4 autowiring exclude ignores subfolders

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Assume following directory structure:

```
/src
  /DTO
    /Factory
      /Collection
```

I want to exclude all classes, including classes from subdirectories of `/DTO` directory

In my services file I do:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

    App\:
    resource: '../src/*
    exclude:
      - '../src/DTO/*'
```

This leads to:

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException : Cannot autowire service App\DTO\Factory\Collection\MyCollection
```

If this service placed in `DTO` folder directly - then **autowiring** works.

Can I specify the **exclude** expression in any way to include subfolders?

Comment: does `'../src/DTO'` work ?

Comment: you contradict to yourself ;). I mean, firstly you say `I want to exclude all classes, including classes from subdirectories of /DTO directory` and then `autowiring is not working`. Of course it won't work, you just excluded classes from autowiring :)

Comment: There is no contradiction. Autowiring should not try to autowire excluded folders. If it tries, then folder is not excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude everything from `DTO` folder use:

```
    App\:
      resource: '../src/*'
      exclude:
        - '../src/DTO'
```

i.e. w/o `*` symbol

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to exclude not only classes placed directly in folder, but also subfolders with two asterisk signs (`**`).

Here is the example of a valid configuration:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

    App\:
    resource: '../src/*
    exclude:
      - '../src/DTO/**'
```

Comment: So what is the difference between using two stars and no stars like the answer you accepted?

Comment: @Cerad sorry for late reply. Actually, I don't know what is the difference. Both ways it works. But I think, accepted answer is more clear, there is no need for additional signs in it